# Failed assertion: line 482 pos 12: 'crossAxisExtent > 0.0': is not true

Tags: flutter

I am new in development, in general, I want to make a Grid list with a custom list but I faced some issues that one of them.

**Categories Screen:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/widgets/category_item.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/dummy_data.dart';

class CategoriesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DeliMeal'),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
            .map(
              (catData) => CategoryItem(
                id: catData.id,
                title: catData.title,
                color: catData.color,
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vertical list, the `crossAxisExtent` is the width of the sliver. So the assertion means that you did not give your widget a width, try wrapping your `GridView` in a `Container` and give it max width, like the following:

```
Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: GridView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20,
      ),
      children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
          .map(
            (catData) => CategoryItem(
              id: catData.id,
              title: catData.title,
              color: catData.color,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
```

You can actually follow the source code of `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent` and see where exactly the assertion is coming from, as you will see, the `crossAxisExtent` is from the `SliverConstraints` class, and you can see its documentation saying :

"The number of pixels in the cross-axis.
For a vertical list, this is the width of the sliver."